# ckeditor: should show empty spans, but not wrap in p

Tags: ckeditor

When I use an empty span, let's say

```
<span class="anchor" id="jumptome"></span>
```

ckeditor removes it.

To the config.js of ckeditor I added

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

    config.IgnoreEmptyParagraphValue = true;
};

CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.span = 0;
```

Now ckeditor does not remove the spans, but they are wrapped in p's like

```
<p><span class="anchor" id="jumptome"></span></p>
```

Is there any configuration to remove the p's (I need the paragraphs for other elements, just want to avoid them for the spans).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need the spans? If you need an anchor, why not use for example a DIV which can be styled to be a visible block in the Editor but an invisible ... anchor in the output content? I do this in my CKE app. Although I use widgets for anchors but same princible anyway.

I'm guessing the reason is because of caret positioning and user targeting - how would the user target that anchor? If it can't be targeted - why do you need it in the contents? Why not something targetable?

Comment: The problem is that I have a complex fluid header. Therefore the class which I want to assign cannot be used with a div, only with a separate span. I just need an anchor, and if I do it with the attribute name='target' it does not work according to the header (which get's smaller when the user scrolls etc.).

Comment: For some reason I need just a span like described above. I hope that it is possible to configure ckeditor accordingly.

Comment: I want to push further, sorry :). How about pre- and post-processing the anchors then? Before loading the content, you transform `<span class="anchor" id="jumptome"></span>` --> `<div class="anchor" id="jumptome"></div>` and then during save, you convert it back. OR maybe better in your case, manually wrap the anchor in a paragraph like `<p class="floob">..span..</p>` and then remove the "wrappings" with before saving? If this is not an option either I'll delete my answer.

Comment: How would you remove the p before saving? you mean via some js-hack in ckeditor?

Comment: With some JS hack, but outside the editor. It's hard to say because I don't know how you update it now. If you for example submit a form with a button, I would attach some code to the button before submitting for example. Or if you save periodically, I'd add it there. Depends on what you do with the CKEditor.